# Lowest level of a Slayer of Terramorphous Class Mod?

Tags: borderlands-2

A [Slayer of Terramorphous](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Slayer_of_Terramorphous) Class Mod is a guaranteed drop (only) from [Terramorphous the Invincible](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Terramorphous_the_Invincible). I believe Terramorphous the Invincible can only be at least level 50 and thus drop at least level 50 items. Can one acquire a Slayer of Terramorphous Class Mod at any level below 50 without the use of such tools as Gibbed's Borderlands 2 Save Editor or Cheat Engine, i.e. without modifying game values from outside of the game client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the quest is level 50 ([You.Will.Die.(Seriously.)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/You._Will._Die._(Seriously.)) and rewards are always tailored towards the Quest-Level I dare to say the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you enter someone else's game and they are on the quest 'You. Will. Die. (Seriously.)', then you have to wait till at least level 50. I managed to find a player nice enough to let me 'piggyback' him on his game, so to speak, and managed to get the class mod for my siren at level 5.

Comment: But is the class mod itself level 5? I suspect not.